# Why the foreach loop using %dopar% don't produce all the results

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, domc

I'm running the code below and get only results for i=1.
How can I get row matrix with **all** the results- i=2 and i=3?

```
library(doMC)
library(foreach)

number_of_cpus=4
cl<-makeCluster(number_of_cpus) 
registerDoMC(cores=4)


split_results2 <-

  foreach(i=1:3, .combine=rbind,  .inorder=TRUE, mc.cores=4) %dopar%  {

  Split_factor=as.character(split_factors[1,i])

  Data$Split_Factor = as.character(Data$Split_Factor)
  Data_new=Data[Data$Split_Factor==Split_factor,]


  GetSplit(Data_new,Data_ind,num_vars,num_factors,r_jobs,probs)  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The foreach function doesn't have an argument named "mc.cores", so it's being treated as an iteration variable, but since you only specified one value for it, it limits the loop to one iteration. Just remove the "mc.cores" argument and it should work the way you expect.

Consider this loop:

```
foreach(i=1:3, j=10) %dopar% {
  c(i, j)
}
```

It is limited by "j", returning a list with one element, while this loop:

```
foreach(i=1:3, j=10:100) %dopar% {
  c(i, j)
}
```

is limited by "i", returning a list with three elements.

Foreach iterates over all of the specified iteration variables in parallel, so the loop is limited by the iteration variable with the fewest number of values. Note that in this respect foreach works differently than "mapply" which recycles the iteration variable with fewer values.

Also note that there's no reason to create the cluster "cl". It's just going to create some extra processes on your machine that won't do anything.

Comment: I have a similar problem - I am passing to foreach dopar only the following:
`i=1:10, .combine = list, .multicombine = TRUE` and yet, the output that I get is of length less than 10. However, since my computation is lengthy and possibly high on memory, is it possible that workers are being killed silently because of memory or any other resources issue?